# step through a string, till you find a '?', then replace everything after it (till the 1st white space) with a given string

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ find and replace (with regex) to do the following:

step through a string, till you find a '?', then replace everything after it (till the 1st white space i.e. end of the 2nd line) with a given new string

Example: (My file looks like this with a few hundred lines)

> hxxp://backwardcompatible/74609/Step/std-origin/face1.bold?**124khcskhskcscnakn497979**
>
> hxxp://backwardcompatible/74609/Step/std-origin/face2.bold?**124khcskhskcscnakn497979**

Desired Return:

> hxxp://backwardcompatible/74609/Step/std-origin/face1.bold?**999999998uuu8865432120ghgf**
>
> hxxp://backwardcompatible/74609/Step/std-origin/face2.bold?**999999998uuu8865432120ghgf**

Comment: You've magically introduced `999999998uuu8865432120ghgf`. Where does that come from? Is that the "given new string"?

Comment: Yes, it's a new string, but this is just an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `\?.*$` in the **Find what** box, and `?999999998uuu8865432120ghgf` in the **Replace with** box.